# Android: Hilt is no using Module, which may be the reason the app is crashing without showing any information

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

This is the situation:

I'm using Compose, Hilt, Navigation and ViewModel. I'm trying to get an instance of my ViewModel within a Composable Screen via Hilt:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel()
) {
...
}
```

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class HomeViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val updateCaptureUseCase: UpdateCaptureUseCase
) : ViewModel() {
...
}
```

```kotlin
class UpdateCaptureUseCase @Inject constructor(private val captureRepository: CaptureRepository) {
...
}
```

I get an instance of **CaptureRepository** by defining it inside a Module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
abstract class CaptureModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindCaptureLocalDataSource(
        captureLocalDataSourceImpl: CaptureLocalDataSourceImpl
    ): CaptureLocalDataSource

    @Binds
    abstract fun bindCaptureRepository(
        captureRepositoryImpl: CaptureRepositoryImpl
    ): CaptureRepository
}
```

The problem is that **CaptureModule** appears in Android Studio as if it had no usages.

I can build and run the app with no problems, but when it is supposed to show **HomeScreen** it crashes. What stresses me out and makes it hard to figure out a solution is that there are no errors in the *Run* tab nor the *Logcat*.

If I remove **updateCaptureUseCase** from the constructor of **HomeViewModel**, then the app works correctly and is able to reach **HomeScreen** without errors. Since **updateCaptureUseCase** depends on **CaptureRepository** and it is being defined in **CaptureModule**, but this Module shows no usages, I suspect the error comes from Hilt and ViewModel

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't [following the documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt-navigation) and using `hiltViewModel()`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I had tried that, but since it didn't fix the errors I thought it was not necessary. Turns out it was part of the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I'm facing a similar issue with the HILT View Model creation, I already am using the annotation on my single activity. Any other idea of what could be causing the problem? My Module (abstract class with binds) also results unused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours I found out a solution: I had to use `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation in my Activity.

The problem is that since I'm fairly new with Compose, Hilt and Navigation I had no idea what structure I should use: I wanted to use a single Activity and instead of using Fragments for navigation I desired to use Composables.

[Android Docs for Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation?gclsrc=ds&gclsrc=ds#addt-resources-samples) provide examples about the structure I wanted; I had set up everything the same, but the only thing that was missing was that annotation. I though it was not needed since I didn't require to inject dependencies directly into the Activity, but in the end this was the root of the bug, a difficult one because the app crashed without showing a single error

Answer (score 2):

I think when `ViewModel` gets initialized hilt checks the dependency graph/tree, and since it has a parameter that also needs a dependency which is the `CaptureRepository` , hilt also looks for it, but because your'e using `@Bind`, afaik, those dependencies should also define `@Inject` annotation.

I was able to reproduce your issue and manage to fix it by, specifying inject to your repository impl

```
class CaptureRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(): CaptureRepository
```

another work around is having your DI module a companion object and define how hilt will `provide` the dependency without the need to specify `@Inject` in your repository impl.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ViewModelComponent::class)
abstract class CaptureModule {
   
    ...
    companion object {

        @Provides
         fun provideHomePresenter(): CaptureRepository {
            return CaptureRepositoryImpl()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, my **CaptureRepositoryImpl** was the same as the one you show. My solution was adding a annotation on my Activity, `@AndroidEntryPoint`